# Form handling with some prefilled data in Play Framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am pretty new in Play Framework, working on play 2.2.0. I want to show one registration form, I know how to show blank form. But I want to pass category along with the FORM[Registration] where category is one of the member of Registration class. Just want to pass the category with Form[Registration], so that in register screen I can show it prefilled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the server side, you need to populate the form with a Registration object that has the category populated, then pass the populated form to the template.  Assuming Registration is a case class with a category member, the result on the server side would look something like:

```
Ok(views.html.index(registrationForm.fill(Registration(category = "New User"))))
```